# Is it possible to hide an empty <table> row with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just starting learning the basics of JavaScript and HTML5. I'm trying to create a cookbook app where users can add recipes. These recipes are stored inside of an array and looped through a table with a for loop. The user can also edit the table. One of the main features is supposed to be that when a row of the table is empty, it automatically gets deleted. I tried using `display: none` with CSS, but it doesn't work. Here is my CSS for the table:

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  let titleRow = table.insertRow();
  let stepsRow = table.insertRow();
  let titleCell = titleRow.insertCell();
  let stepsCell = stepsRow.insertCell();
  titleCell.innerHTML = inputTitle.value;
  stepsCell.innerHTML = inputSteps.value;
  titleCell.contentEditable = true;
  stepsCell.contentEditable = true;
  inputTitle.value = inputTitle.defaultValue;
  inputSteps.value = inputSteps.defaultValue;
}, false);
```

```css
td: empty {
    display: none;
}
tr: empty {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
           <label>Insert Recipe: </label>
        <textarea id = "inputTitle" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Recipe Title"></textarea>
           <textarea id = "inputSteps" rows = "5" cols = "50" placeholder="Recipe Steps"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Add Recipe</button>
</form>
<table id = "table"></table>
```

The `table` element refers to an HTML5 table, `inputTitle` refers to one `textarea`, and `inputSteps` refers a different `textarea`.

I may have mistakes in my JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Provide snippet code! That help us to fix your problem

Comment: There should not be a space before `empty` . ie. `td:empty { ... }`

Comment: `:empty` will only select elements that contain _nothing_. White-space characters, line breaks, other empty elements etc. will all prevent `:empty` from working. This would likely prevent your `tr:empty` selector from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since you aren't submitting the data to any other resource, you shouldn't be using a `form` or a `submit` button.

Now, the simplest solution is to just perform validation on the inputs before building the table. if the input is empty, don't build those rows.

Lastly, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't contain any HTML. Use `.textContent` instead because `.innerHTML` has performance and security considerations.

```js
let inputTitle = document.getElementById("inputTitle");
let inputSteps = document.getElementById("inputSteps");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  // First, just check to see if there was valid input
  if(!inputTitle.value || !inputSteps.value){
    alert("You must fill in a title and a recipe");
    return;  // Exit function
  }
  let titleRow = table.insertRow();
  let stepsRow = table.insertRow();
  let titleCell = titleRow.insertCell();
  let stepsCell = stepsRow.insertCell();
  titleCell.textContent = inputTitle.value;
  stepsCell.textContent = inputSteps.value;
  titleCell.contentEditable = true;
  stepsCell.contentEditable = true;
});
```

```html
<label>Insert Recipe: </label>
<textarea id = "inputTitle" rows="1" cols="50" placeholder="Recipe Title"></textarea>
<textarea id = "inputSteps" rows = "5" cols = "50" placeholder="Recipe Steps"></textarea>
<button type="button">Add Recipe</button>
<table id = "table"></table>
```

Comment: The question was about hiding empty table cells.

Comment: @Turnip Yes, but often times the OPs have coded themselves into situations that they didn't realize they could avoid in the first place. This is one of those.

Comment: actually I agree with turnip

Comment: @JSProgrammer Without validation, you'll have to loop over each cell of the new row and determine if they are all empty. Then, if they are, you'll have to either remove or hide the row. Can this be done? Sure, is this how anyone would do it? Certainly not. Form validation exists for exact circumstances such as this - to prevent bad data that would then make you have to accommodate for it in your program.

Comment: @JSProgrammer No, it won't, which is why validation is the proper solution. The `:empty` CSS Pseudo-class only matches an element that has no child content. `<tr>` elements will still have `<td>` children even when the row is empty, so you can't use it there and `<td>` elements may wind up with whitespace, which would be a false positive. CSS is not the answer here. Validation should always be used when there is user input and it solves this issue quite easily.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ScottMarcus It seems that today `:empty` can matches empty rows even with <td> inside, but not with filled pseudo-elements. Tested on Firefox and Chomium.